# didSelectItemAtIndexPath of UICollectionView not getting called when its in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

[image]

I have taken the `UIScrollView` inside that
  i have taken one `UIView` with fixed 
position and just below it taken `UICollectionView` which is horizontal scrolling, 
then i have again `UIView` and then again i have taken 
`UICollectionView` with fixed cell 1. 
So, on select of item of both collection view's `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method not getting called.I have found some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050053/didselectitematindexpath-of-uicollectionview-inside-of-a-uiscrollview-is-not-get) but not found exact one.

By using above solution, i am facing problem is **on tap anywhere(ex. image gallary)** tap of `UIScrollview` call the tap method but every time `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` called wheather i click on collection view or not default zero `indexpath` is called.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureAction:)];
[recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
self.scrollViu.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.scrollViu addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


-(void)gestureAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.YourCollectionViewName];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.YourCollectionViewName indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchLocation];
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.item);
}
```

Comment: You need to rethink your UI design approach. That sounds overly complicated and messy. The issue here is which view should be receiving the touch event and since you have a scrollview, and two collection views you can expect unexpected behaviour like this.

Comment: Right, @Tander above solution is working for single uicollection and i have tryed also, Is there any any solution for this kind of UI can you suggest me ?

Comment: Yea.. just have one UICollectionView divided into 4 sections. Set scrolling for horizontal. And have the collectionView in a UIScrollView so you have vertical scroll.

Comment: Thanks, for suggest me ...! Finally i have also found one solution for above UI which i need to just add UITapGestureRecognizer in to appropriate collectionview instead of UIScrollView its also working correctly. I know Your ui design way is better than this next time i will keep in mind. Thanks Man... :)  @Tander

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Comment: @Tander I have Rethinked again for this UI i have one question, how can we set scroll horizontal or vertical based on section of UICollectionView ? for single section i khow.  UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*) self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;

Comment: I thought all your UICollectionViews were horizontal scroll ?

Comment: @Tander No, I am talking about the your UI design way where in one collectionview's first and second section has horizontal scroll like for image gallery and other third section has items i want to scroll verically. As i show you in screenshot.